# Why is it printing all comments from included file to the screen?

Tags: javascript, ssi

I'm working with classic asp on server including the javascript file in the document like this:

```
<!--#include virtual="datoteke/jsPDF-master/jspdf.js"-->
```

...when i run my file on server, browser prints all the comments from included files to the screen. I tried to include it also like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsPDF-master/jspdf.js"></script>
```

...it worked on localhost, but on server it doesn't, i get an error when i create an instance to the class in my javascript file: "[object Error]"

Why is it printing all those comments to the screen and how do I actually include javascript on server side? What did i do wrong?

Comment: I don't know ASP, but does `<!--#include` add `<script>` tags, or does it just literally include the text of the file there?  Are you sure you don't need to do: `<script><!--#include virtual="datoteke/jsPDF-master/jspdf.js"--></script>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser looks for JavaScript code in `<script>` tags. Your first statement does not seem to include those tags at all. I guess you want something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--#include virtual="datoteke/jsPDF-master/jspdf.js"-->
</script>
```

You should also know that the [`virtual` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html#includevirtual) makes a subrequest to load the file through the web server, which I suspect don't need/want. [Give `file` a try](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html#element.include).

---

**Edit:** There's a quite nice [article about SSI in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes). Please note that IIS supports Server-Side Includes but it isn't related to ASP Classic at all.